# Generate Entity Framework model on database without direct access

Tags: visual-studio-2013, entity-framework-6

I would like to create a model from a database.
This is easy enough to do in visual studio using the wizards, BUT what happens when one does not have direct access to a database?

My database is on another network completely, and there is no VPN access. In other words, my visual studio can not see the database.

Is there a way for me to run this wizard remotely? Or any console apps within visual studio that I can transfer across and run on that side?

Comment: I suspect you would need the data structure: export the schema as a script from the database and use that to build a matching db (but without any data) that you can access. (If you don't have access to a database how are you going to test and debug your application?)

Comment: Run remotely, and pray to the gods of programming :) also lots of log files. I have tried bringing the schema across. but there are issues with Filestreams etc

Comment: Another option would be code first. But that means writing the definitions by hand (but probably easier than manually adding everything in the designer).